# R10 Boot Timeout Error - Conceptual

Tags: python, heroku

So I'm getting the very common

"Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch"

But none of the solutions I've tried have worked, so my question is much more conceptual.

What is suppose to be binding? It is my understanding that I do not need to write code specifically to bind the worker dyno to the $PORT, but rather that this failure is caused primarily by computationally intensive processes.

I don't have any really great code snippets to show here, but I've included the link to the github repo for the project I'm working on.

https://github.com/therightnee/RainbowReader_MKII

There is a long start up time when the RSS feeds are first parsed, but I've never seen it go past 30 seconds. Even so, currently when you go to the page it should just render a template. Initially, in this setup, there is no data processing being done. Testing locally, everything runs great, and even with the data parsing it doesn't take more than a minute in any test case.

This leads me to believe that somewhere I need to be setting or using the $PORT variable in some way but I don't know.

Thanks!